# Adding an int to an observable collection is causing an invocation error

Tags: c#, integer, observablecollection

Function below looks to add an `int` to an `ObservableCollection<int>`

```cs
public void ApplyHighlight()
{
    var currentPos = HighlightService.GetSelectedPosition(Delimiters.ToArray());
    if (EdiTransaction.PositionHighlights.Contains(currentPos.Item1))
    {
        EdiTransaction.PositionHighlights.Remove(currentPos.Item1);
    }
    else
    {
        EdiTransaction.PositionHighlights.Add(currentPos.Item1);
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm receiving when the item tries to get added:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[System.Int32]` to type `System.Int32[]`.

May anyone explain this to me?

Comment: A collection is not an array. The latter is expected. Have you tried using `currentPos.Item1.ToArray()` ?

Comment: You cannot `ToArray()` an `int` which is what type `currentPos.Item1` is.

Comment: Then the Errormessage does not match your codesnippet. Or it happens not on the line you think it does. Post a [mcve].

Comment: What line exactly does this error occur. You obviously have some type mismatch and at least one of you variables is not what you think it is. Or the error does not happen in the shown snippet

Comment: I don't se any cast in this code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I read a bit about the data type, from this documentation article: [ObservableCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0)

Try this:

```
EdiTransaction.PositionHighlights.Add(currentPos.Item1.Items.ToArray());
```